# saving chats using chatadapter

Tags: android, save, chat

I am using a custom chatadapter that I use to make a simple chat program with multiple user. However as soon as I leave the chat activity all the messages are gone. What would I have to do to save all the messages of that chat history and then put them back in the chat window when the user opens up the chat? The chats are in a listview. I am new to JAVA so I am not fully aware on how to go about this. If I understand correctly I would have to use SQL. Can anyone guide me as to the efficient way to do this? Thanks

Comment: I think your question is too broad for stack overflow. Most importantly you haven't yet tried to solve the problem yourself. Search for some tutorials on how to use SQL database in Android app, there is plenty, you should be able to at least start off

Comment: Yeah but I wanna know if that would be the correct way to go about it. My question is basically how can I save a chat and fill the chat up again once its opened?

Answer (score 3):

Best thing to go about this is use SQLlite database. As chats volumes may be high and better to avoid service call to load huge data set. Also, local database required for handling network connect/disconnect(you might need to retry messages which are not being sent during network glitch).

You can take reference from Applozic's [open source client repo](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK).

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to keep more than few messages and chats in your app, and access them efficiently, then yes - database would definitely be the good way to approach this problem.